# Why was taxonomist badge not awarded, is it broken?

Tags: support, badges, taxonomist-badge

I remember being the creator of the iis-7.5 tag with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805233/will-i-have-to-rewrite-any-major-pieces-of-code-for-iis7-5) question. Since then it has had 324 questions tag with it. Any idea?

[image]

EDIT: after reading the comments from the moderators, I feel this 'error' is unfair to users trying to tag content. I created the tag in good faith to match other naming conventions for iis5, iis6, iis7. Another user comes along and edits it (incorrectly) and my tag is thus deleted. Users will choose whatever tag shows up in the auto-complete list, and in this case my tag is now gone, and iis-7.5 shows up instead. I feel that this takes away part of the incentive to add tags to new content.

Comment: Nobody can "steal" a tag from you, they can retag your posts.  If you create a tag, it is yours forever.  However, if the community decides not to use your tag (regardless of whether or not it follows convention), there's little to complain about.  Instead of complaining about moderators supporting retagging, suggesting a retag to fall in line with existing naming conventions would have been more productive.

Comment: @Daniel: the problem is that the community uses whatever tag shows up in the auto-complete list. In this case, mine was REMOVED from that list, and replaced by Helen's erroneous tag, therefor the credit is taken away from me. I named my tag in good faith to match the iis5, iis6, iis7 format.

Comment: I understand the problem, and suggested a better course of action.  You can suggest a retag in favor of [tag:iis7.5] to follow conventions.

Comment: @Daniel: another comment to your original statement here "If you create a tag, it is yours forever.", I would like to see if this is the case. Now iis7.5 has been setup as a synonym, so it doesn't sound like I own any tag.

Answer (score 2):

You created the [iis7.5](/questions/tagged/iis7.5) tag. [Helen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113116/helen) [edited your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/805233/revisions) a few months later to replace it with the [iis-7.5](/questions/tagged/iis-7.5) tag, which matches most other tags (there's usually a `-` between the name and version). There's now a [synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/iis-7.5/synonyms) mapping your old tag to the new one

Comment: Is that not the same as me creating the tag? Mine is still the first question with that tag.

Comment: @Raymond It's not; the creator is the person who first added the tag to a post, regardless of who owns that post

Comment: I disagree here, I am sure it was unintentional on Helen's part, but this feels like an attempt to 'game' the system. If you look at all other 'version' tags for iis, there is no - in them. I edited my post to include a screenshot showing you exactly this example.

Comment: @Raymond Regardless of whether or not all of the tags follow convention, you created [iis7.5], not [iis-7.5], and the latter is the one that has 325.

Comment: Interestingly enough, Helen did not get Taxonomist for this tag either: http://stackoverflow.com/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=113116

Comment: @grace: again i disagree. the only reason 'iis-7.5' has those is because it shows up in the auto-complete list. had helens erroneous edit not been performed then it would have been on my original tag.

Comment: @Daniel Helen may not have actually been the first to use it, she's just the one who added it to Raymond's post. It doesn't really matter; the point is Raymond is not the one who made it

Comment: @Raymond Apparently the iis tags don't follow the convention, but most do. I don't know how the iis-7.5 divergence came about, but this is the answer to your question; the iis7.5 tag doesn't have enough instances (since it's a synonym, it was probably merged and has 0 instances)

Comment: Alternatively, Michael, she earned the Taxonomist badge early. You can only earn the badge once, so once you've earned it for one tag, it doesn't matter how many tags you create.

Comment: @Grace Oh, I assumed she didn't have it; that might be it too

Comment: This still seems wrong here. I created a tag, somebody came and edited in a new one instead, deleting my old one, and even though it was incorrect, I do not get credit for the creation of the tag. Let's be honest here and admit that the only reason iis-7.5 is used more than iis7.5 is because MINE no longer exists in the auto-complete. Had Helen not done this *incorrect* action, then I would have 325 posts with my tag instead. I still feel I should be getting credit here.

Comment: Although I will yield, that if it can be shown that 'iis-7.5' tag existed before I created 'iis7.5', then obviously I don't deserve the credit.

Comment: I wholeheartedly appreciate the enthusiasm for SO, but reading through this reminds me of: http://twitter.com/whitegrlproblem